# Java. Group and sum exact values in collection of Java Objects

Tags: java, collections, stream, java-stream, pojo

Aaaah, it's finally happened, and I asking for help :(

Let's start:
I have a list of incoming transactions, for example:

```
List<FinancialTransaction> incomingTransactions = new ArrayList();
incomingTransactions.add(new FinancialTransaction(1, 1, 2, 1000000));
incomingTransactions.add(new FinancialTransaction(2, 1, 2, 2000000));
incomingTransactions.add(new FinancialTransaction(3, 2, 1, 1000000));
incomingTransactions.add(new FinancialTransaction(4, 2, 1, 4000000));
incomingTransactions.add(new FinancialTransaction(5, 2, 3, 1000000));
```

FinancialTransaction POJO:

```
public class FinancialTransaction {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer srcId;

    private Integer dstId;

    private Long amount;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //getters, setters, constructors, toString
}
```

Then incomingTransactions moves to method listed below, which must create a new Map, with a key of srcId and dstId of FinancialTransaction, group by this key, sum "amount" value of grouped objects, and put new object with Id = sdcId and dstId, srcId = this.srcId, dstId = this.dstId, and amount = sum of all grouped objects:

```
public class TransactionMerger {


    public static Map<String, FinancialTransaction> mergeTransactions(List<FinancialTransaction> financialTransactions) {

        Map<String, FinancialTransaction> mergedTransactions = new HashMap<>();

        for (FinancialTransaction ft: financialTransactions) {

            String key = ft.getSrcId() + "" + ft.getDstId();

            if (mergedTransactions.get(key) != null) {
                mergedTransactions.put(key, ft);
            } else {
//          Don't know to write here :/
            }

        }

        financialTransactions.clear();

        return mergedTransactions;
    }

}
```

This method must absorb incomingTransactions return something like:

```
Key: 12 Value: FinancialTransaction {12, 1, 2, 3000000} //summed first and second values in incoming list
Key: 21 Value: FinancialTransaction {21, 2, 1, 5000000} //summed third and fourth values in incoming list
Key: 23 Value: FinancialTransaction {23, 2, 3, 1000000} //returned fifth values
```

Please help I have no Ideas, I already know how to group with composite key, from several values, but ho to sum and group - have no ideas please help!!!!!

Big thx guys!!!

Comment: I hope you have only 9 source/dest IDs, because otherwise your key will be ambiguous (e.g. `12 + "" + 3` and `1 + "" + 23`)

Comment: Are you aware of the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method?

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah, thanks you I overlooked this case :( Maybe I will add some nulls before numbers, to make smth like scr - 000001+ dst - 000002 = key- 000001000002, is it bad or not?

Comment: or just put a colon between.

Comment: @AndyTurner Brilliantly! thx)))

Comment: as for merge method - yeah a little)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Map<String, FinancialTransaction> mergeTransactions(List<FinancialTransaction> financialTransactions) {

        Map<String, FinancialTransaction> mergedTransactions = new HashMap<>();

        for (FinancialTransaction ft: financialTransactions) {

            String key = ft.getSrcId() + "" + ft.getDstId();

            if (mergedTransactions.containsKey(key)) {
                //get the existing FinancialTransaction for the key and updates it's amount only
                mergedTransactions.get(key).setAmount(mergedTransactions.get(key).getAmount() + ft.getAmount());
            } else {
                //create new FinancialTransaction object for the map
                FinancialTransaction financialTransaction = new FinancialTransaction();
                //do not set Id for the new object, as its not db generated, key will behave like id
                financialTransaction.setSrcId(ft.getSrcId());
                financialTransaction.setDstId(ft.getDstId());
                financialTransaction.setAmount(ft.getAmount());
                mergedTransactions.put(key, financialTransaction);
            }
        }

        financialTransactions.clear();
        return mergedTransactions;
    }
```

Hope this helps. I have added comments let me know if you need more clarity.

Comment: Thx Raushan, it works perfectly! It's simple and clear now for me! Big thx!!!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you, but I recommend you to read @Andy's comment on the question. He pointed out the design issue in your current implementation, hopefully you would have noticed that on your own and are working/analysed with the solution you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create merge function in your `FinancialTransaction`or in utility. for now, I'm adding in the above class.

```
public static FinancialTransaction merge(FinancialTransaction first, FinancialTransaction second){
  first.setAmount(first.getAmount() + second.getAmount());
  return first;
}
```

And now , let's group using `map.merge`

```
incomingTransactions.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(trxn -> trxn.getSrcId() + "" + trxn.getDstId(), Function.identity() , FinancialTransaction::merge));
```

Here, the grouping will be done using the generated key and when we will encounter duplicate key (or similar transaction), it will apply merge function which will basically sum and return an updated reference for financial transaction.

Note: As pointed out in comments, be careful how you generate your key for grouping.